Discrete Convexity of a Function
Let $Y \mid p \sim \text{Binomial}(x, p)$ and $Z \sim \text{Uniform}\{a, b\}$, where $a$, $b$, $x$ are non-negative integers and $a < b$. I am trying to prove that for any fixed probability $p$, $\mathbb{E}[\max(Z - Y, 0) \mid p]$ is convex for $a \le x \le b$. My attempts to prove the convexity are as follows:
Let $R(x) = \mathbb{E}[\max(Z-Y,0) \mid p]$. To prove that $R$ is convex in $x$, it is sufficient to show that for any non-negative integer $x$, we have $2\cdot R(x) \le R(x+1)+R(x-1)$, or equivalently,
\begin{equation} \label{maininequality2}
2\cdot R(x) - R(x+1)-R(x-1) \le 0. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Let $1_{\{y > z\}}$ be a binary indicator that is equal to 1 if $z-y<0$ and $0$ otherwise. For $a \le x \le b$, $\mathbb{E}[\max(Z-Y,0) \mid p]$ can be expressed as:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\mathbb{E}[\max(Z-Y,0) \mid p] &= &&\sum_{y=0}^{x} \sum_{z=a}^{b} \max(z-y,0) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z=z) \\
& = &&\sum_{y=0}^{x} \sum_{z=a}^{b} z \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z=z) - \sum_{y = 0}^{x} \sum_{z=a}^{b} y \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z=z) \\
&-&& \sum_{y=0}^{x} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z=z) \\
& = &&\sum_{y=0}^{x} \mathbb{P}(Y=y) \cdot \sum_{z=a}^{b} z \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z=z) - \sum_{y = 0}^{x}  y \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y) \cdot \sum_{z=a}^{b} \mathbb{P}(Z=z) \\
&-&& \sum_{y=0}^{x} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z=z) \\
& = && \frac{a+b}{2} - \sum_{y = 0}^{x}  y \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y) - \sum_{y=0}^{x} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z=z)
\end{alignat*}
Substituting the value of $\mathbb{E}[\max(Z-Y,0) \mid p]$ in (1) I can get
\begin{alignat*}{2}
& && 2 \cdot \frac{a+b}{2} - 2\underbrace{\sum_{y = 0}^{x}  y \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y)}_{=px,\text{expected value}} - 2\sum_{y=0}^{x} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z=z) \\
& && -\frac{a+b}{2} + \underbrace{\sum_{y = 0}^{x+1}  y \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y)}_{=p(x+1),\text{expected value}} + \sum_{y=0}^{x+1} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z=z) \\
& && -\frac{a+b}{2} + \underbrace{\sum_{y = 0}^{x-1}  y \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y)}_{=p(x-1),\text{expected value}} + \sum_{y=0}^{x-1} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z=z)\\
& =&& -2 \cdot px - 2\sum_{y=0}^{x} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \binom{x}{y} p^{y} (1-p)^{x-y} \cdot \frac{1}{b-a+1} \\
& && +p(x+1) + \sum_{y=0}^{x+1} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \binom{x+1}{y} p^{y} (1-p)^{x+1-y} \cdot \frac{1}{b-a+1} \\
& && +p(x-1) + \sum_{y=0}^{x-1} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \binom{x-1}{y} p^{y} (1-p)^{x-1-y} \cdot \frac{1}{b-a+1}\\
& =&& - 2\sum_{y=0}^{x} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \binom{x}{y} p^{y} (1-p)^{x-y} \cdot \frac{1}{b-a+1} \\
& && + \sum_{y=0}^{x+1} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \binom{x+1}{y} p^{y} (1-p)^{x+1-y} \cdot \frac{1}{b-a+1} \\
& && + \sum_{y=0}^{x-1} \sum_{z=a}^{b} 1_{\{y > z\}} \cdot (z-y) \cdot \binom{x-1}{y} p^{y} (1-p)^{x-1-y} \cdot \frac{1}{b-a+1} \le 0
\end{alignat*}
I am having trouble simplifying the above sum to show that the above inequality holds.

Note that you can write that $Y\equiv Y_x=W_1+\dots+W_x$ where $W_i$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli($p$) random variables. Hence
\begin{align}
&R(x+1)+R(x-1)-2R(x)=\mathbb{E}\max(Z-W_1-\dots-W_{x+1},0)
\\&+\mathbb{E}\max(Z-W_1-\dots-W_{x-1},0)
 -2\mathbb{E}\max(Z-W_1-\dots-W_{x},0)
\\ &=\mathbb{E}\max(A-W_{x+1},0)+\mathbb{E}\max(A+W_x,0)-2\mathbb{E}\max(A,0)
\\ &=\mathbb{E}\max(A-W_{x+1},0)+\mathbb{E}\max(A+W_{x+1},0)-2\mathbb{E}\max(A,0)
\\ & =\mathbb{E}\left[\max(A-W_{x+1},0)+\max(A+W_{x+1},0)-2\max(A,0)\right]
\\ & =\mathbb{E} f(A,W_{x+1})
\end{align}
where $A=Z-W_1-\dots-W_{x-1}-W_x$, since
$$
\mathbb{E}\max(A+W_{x},0)=\mathbb{E}\max(A+W_{x+1},0),
$$
$$
f(c,d)=\max(c+d,0)+\max(c-d,0)-2\max(c,0)
$$
because $A$, $W_x$, $W_{x+1}$ are all independent.
Now it's easy to work out that $f(c,d)\ge 0$ for all $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$  (if $c<0$ then $f(c,d)= \max(c+d,0)+\max(c-d,0)\ge 0$ and if $c\ge 0$ then  $f(c,d)=\max(|d|-c,0)\ge 0$.)
As a result,
$$
R(x+1)+R(x-1)-2R(x)=\mathbb{E} f(A,W_{x+1})\ge 0
$$
as required.

That's neat! I did not think it that way. Just need a clarification; $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$, right?

Thanks. No, it's true for any $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, not just integers.
